# Where is libglfw stored?

Tags: apt, opengl, shared-library

I installed `libglfw` using `apt`. I looked at `/lib`, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` but the library is not there. Where is it stored?

Comment: See: https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/amd64/libglfw3/filelist

Comment: `dpkg -L libglfw` will show. ...... (( /usr/lib/ : Changed ten years ago, with Ubuntu 11.04 → it is now mostly `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` ))